# Rest architecture

Tags: rest, architecture, zend-framework2

I need some software architecture advice. Me and my colleagues have the task to build billing system + e-cart on rest core. I mean, the rest core, should make the calculations and to hold the business logic. The client, should make the simplest possible queries to the core.

So, here I need architecture advice, is this OK from paradigm side, and which is the best way to build it. We chosen the zend framework 2 as a core (Apigility), but my concerns, are how to make dependencies between modules. For example, how to make query to the API: "Give me all users, with products and orders". I think, the rest should not perform this kind of requests.

What do you think? Is it OK, to build this kind of rest application or to stick to the best web practices?

Comment: GET /users?expand=products,orders

Comment: Use a service layer for your business logic, which is then used by both your RESTful controllers AND by other modules requiring it.